# Getting the space key to act like the return key

Tags: macos, keyboard

I come from a Windows background and I have gotten into the habit of hitting the Space key every time there's a popup on my screen that I want to close.  But on the Mac, it doesn't do anything, but hitting Return does.  Does anyone  know how I can get Mac to let the space key act like the Return key on modal dialogs?  I tried to find something in the Keyboard preferences but don't see anything related to popups.

Comment: You could try a key remapping program. At lifehacker (http://lifehacker.com/5882684/the-best-keyboard-remapper-for-mac-os-x) the KeyRemap4MacBook (http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) is recommended. I've not tried it, but it might work for you.

Comment: i think the issue is not that space needs to be return, but that space should be able to interact with dialog boxes

Comment: Can we improve things to get you to indicate which answer works to solve your question?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the proposed solutions does exactly what I asked for, but I have to assume that getting the exact functionality won't be possible at this point in time.

Comment: It sounds like you're after the Windows method *because* its the Windows method. With most things Mac vs Windows, the same will be achievable with much the same efficiency, but you'll need to 'Think Different' as they say. The interface or method will be a little different, and if you try to make one *just* like the other, you'll be disappointed. If you can manage to drop the expectations of one behaving exactly like the other (and it goes both ways!) then you'll find efficient, but slightly different, ways of working on either system.

Comment: The Windows method (of invoking selected button on Enter) is also how things behave on the Web and Linux. So it's not just the Windows method. If one could swap the behaviors of 'Enter' and 'Space' on the Mac, that would be really helpful.

Comment: You don't see anything... because what you call "popups" are *dialogs*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to enable Full Keyboard Access. This setting is also available in the System Preferences under the Keyboard preference pane:

[image]

By selecting 'All controls', you can <kbd>tab</kbd> around keyboard focus between the various widgets in dialog boxes, including buttons like **OK** or **Cancel**. It's slightly different from Windows, in that <kbd>return</kbd> is like pressing the **fully highlighted** button, while <kbd>space</kbd> is like pressing the **selected / outlined** button.

This image shows the difference between the two:

[image]

In this example, the **Cancel** button has focus (from tabbing) while **OK** is the default. So pressing <kbd>space</kbd> would select **Cancel**, while <kbd>return</kbd> would select **OK**.

And for completeness, this one can be accepted by either <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd>:

[image]

It's worth noting that some OS X dialog boxes (I've noticed this especially with dialogs asking whether it's OK to overwrite a file) will come up with, for example, **Don't Overwrite** as the default for <kbd>return</kbd>, and **Do Overwrite** as the focused item for <kbd>space</kbd>. This makes it a single key either way to do what you want, but you need to be sure you've got the right one!

Comment: Awesome! This is precisely THE way to get that functionality.

Comment: Selecting this answer, but note that it is not the exact behavior of Windows since I do have to tab around before I can hit the space, where as in Windows tab was typically not necessary since the focus was usually on the main button of interest (like OK or Save).  But I have a feeling this is the closest we can get.

Comment: I believe this behaviour is changed in macOS Ventura - do you agree?  Now when I get a dialog there is no highlighted button, just a selected button (highlighted border like "Cancel" in pic above).  Does anyone have a solution to get macOS to revert to previous behaviour?