# OS X dialogs: Can I use 'Enter' to invoke the *currently selected* button instead of the default one?

Tags: macos, keyboard, dialog, space

In an OS X dialog, there a way to make 'Enter/Return' invoke the *currently selected* button instead of the *default* one (and, if possible, make 'Space' invoke the *default* button instead). That is, can I swap the behaviors of 'Space' and 'Enter' in this situation?

[This would keep this behavior consistent with that of the web's, and other platforms like Windows and Linux]

Comment: This UX behavior bothers me to where this should be fixed upon pain of death.  Modal alerts are evil because they interrupt users.  Modal alerts without keyboard shortcuts are embarrassingly stupid.  Alerts should be batched in one system, like email, so they can be handled at will.

Comment: What do you mean by "currently selected" ? In a Mac dialog, traditionally, there is no way to select a button, we can only activate the button — usually by clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:  Explained here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69305/44377

Also, I use [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/) to find most-if-not-all shortcuts in any context.

Comment: I already had that option selected. It has, afaik, nothing to do with what I am asking - i.e using 'Enter' to invoke the selected button instead of 'Space'

Comment: My bad.  Updated. :)

Comment: The link just explains how to use the 'Space' and 'Enter' keys to invoke buttons in a dialog, but says nothing about how to swap their behaviors :)